# sudo git clone git://ram.umd.edu/ros/gps_umd.git

Tags: ros, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This command does not work because the link is dead.  I need help getting it to work in ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202548/sudo-git-clone-git://ram.umd.edu/ros/gps_umd.git/) by [snowman13th](https://answers.ros.org/users/21577/snowman13th/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like `ram.umd.edu` does not serve those git repositories anymore, and it looks like it has been like that for some time (see [link for umd-ros-pkg expired. Please update](http://answers.ros.org/question/43488/link-for-umd-ros-pkg-expired-please-update/) fi).

It would appear however that Ken Tossell has a fork on his github account: [github.com/ktossell/gps_umd](https://github.com/ktossell/gps_umd) (from: [wiki.ros.org/gps_umd](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_umd)). Perhaps you can use that?

PS: why the `sudo`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3